# Find the work done by $F$ when it moves a particle from the origin to the point (2,-1,-2) on $C$, by performing a line integra

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following question and I am not 100% sure on how to proceed. I think I have answered a) but I'm not entirely sure if it's correct

Consider the path $C$ which follows the curve $y=-(\frac{x}{2})^\frac{3}{2}$ lying in the plane $x=-z$, from the origin to the point (2,-1,-2).
Also consider the vector field $$F = (z^3+x^3)i + 2yj + 3z^2xk$$ 
(a) Find a parametrisation for $C$, including the possible values of the parameter. ($x=2t$)

By letting $t=\frac{x}{2}$ this implies $$x = 2t$$ $$z = -x \implies z = -2t$$ $$y = -(t)^\frac{3}{2}$$
This then means the parameterisation is $$ r(t) = (2t, -t^\frac{3}{2}, -2t)$$

(b) Hence calculate the length of C.

(c) Find the work done by $F$ when it moves a particle from the origin to the point (2,-1,-2) on $C$, by performing a line integral

(d) For the vector field $F$, find an associated potential function.

Answer (score 0):

Your (a) is correct. You also need to figure out the lower and upper limits for $t$.

Hints for b,c,d:

b. Arc length is $\int_a^b ||\vec{r}'(t)||dt=\int^b_a \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2+(\frac{dz}{dt})^2} dt$.

c. The formula for line integral is $\int_a^b F(\vec{r}(t))\cdot \vec{r}'(t) dt$. If you are learning mulivariable calculus, you should have learned this.

d. Follow the example here to do it: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ConservativeVectorField.aspx